# Laravel Model Serialization with DB transaction

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an event that should be triggered, however, when I call create method which uses `DB::transaction`, I get an error message saying `No query results for model [App\Model\Order\Order]`. I understand I get the error message because the event is trying to serialize `OrderModel` which is not created yet because of `DB::transaction`.

What can be done to avoid this error?

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

**Controller**

```
public function create() {
    DB::transaction(function () {
         $order = OrderModel::create([
                 'content' => 'bla bla'
             ]);

         event(new OrderDispatched($order));

         .... some other logics...
    });


    return response($order, 200);
}
```

**Event**

```
class OrderDispatched implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('need-refresh');
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->order->id,
            'carrier_team_id' => $this->order->carrier_team_id
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the other syntax of Laravel transactions:

```
public function create() 
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        $order = OrderModel::create([
            'content' => 'bla bla'
        ]);

        DB::commit();

        // ... some other logic ...
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        return response('Error', 500);
    }

    event(new OrderDispatched($order));

    return response($order, 200);
}
```

This way you'll only send the event if the transaction didn't fail.